# Add 2 parameters to Email Template Body

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a email template and i have bind 1 parameter to it(this.OrderCode) and it's working .So now i need to bind another one.

Email Template Like Below,

```
string OrderTemplate="<p><%=this.OrderCode%></p><p><%=this.ReferredTo%></p>";

tempValues comes like below,
[0]this.OrderCode
[1]ODR5000
[2]this.ReferredTo
[3]Janez Smithson
```

Using below code i need to show both of above values.In here only shows 1st value only(ODR5000)

```
public string EmailTemplate(string OrderTemplate, params string[] tempValues)
        {
            string templatebody = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                templatebody = OrderTemplate;
                for (var i = 0; i < tempValues.Length; i++)
                {
                    templatebody= templatebody.Replace("<%={0}%>".FormatWith(tempValues[i]), tempValues++);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                Log4NetLogger.Log(ex);
            }
            return templatebody;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have pretty similar function for that.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tempValues.Length; i++)
{
    var pattern = string.Format(@"(\[{0}\])", i);
    templatebody = Regex.Replace(templatebody, pattern, tempValues[i].ToString());
}
```